# Peach Payment Getaway - Authentication Token Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment-gateway, payment

I'm currently encountering difficulties obtaining an authentication token through the provided endpoint

Here are the details of the issue:

Endpoint for Authentication Token:
https://testsecure.peachpayments.com/checkout/api/oauth/token

Request:

```
{
    "clientId": "{{cliendId}}",
    "clientSecret": "{{clientSecret}}",
    "merchantId": "{{merchantId}}"
}
```

Response:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Despite providing the necessary parameters, the response indicates a "Missing Authentication Token" error. I have double-checked the provided credentials, but the issue persists.

Comment: in which header do you put that request?